# How to make one common JpaRepository for several classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

I am writing a `Rest` application using `Spring-Boot`, `MVC`, `Jpa (Hibernate)`. I have reference classes that store, for example, the names of `countries`, `manufacturers`, `types of coffee`, etc. They all inherit from `GeneralCatalog` via inheritance *@MappedSuperClass*. It turns out to be too much code and interfaces when working with them. How can you reduce the number of interfaces, as well as the code in the controllers. Moreover, the methods are the same. Maybe you can create one common interface for all of them?

Class GeneralCatalog:

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GeneralCatalog {

    protected  @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    protected String name;

    protected boolean isDeleted;
}
```

Countries:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Countries extends GeneralCatalog{
}
```

...

All classes are also inherited without their extra lines.

CatalogService:

```java
@Service
public class CatalogService {

    // Fields
    //
    private CountriesRepository countriesRepository;

    private ManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository;

    private RoastingRepository roastingRepository;

    private PackagingRepository packagingRepository;

    private TeaColorRepository teaColorRepository;

    private CoffeeTypeRepository coffeeTypeRepository;

    private TeaTypeRepository teaTypeRepository;


    // Setters
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setCountriesRepository(CountriesRepository countriesRepository) {
        this.countriesRepository = countriesRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setManufacturerRepository(ManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository) {
        this.manufacturerRepository = manufacturerRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRoastingRepository(RoastingRepository roastingRepository) {
        this.roastingRepository = roastingRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPackagingRepository(PackagingRepository packagingRepository) {
        this.packagingRepository = packagingRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTeaColorRepository(TeaColorRepository teaColorRepository) {
        this.teaColorRepository = teaColorRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCoffeeTypeRepository(CoffeeTypeRepository coffeeTypeRepository) {
        this.coffeeTypeRepository = coffeeTypeRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTeaTypeRepository(TeaTypeRepository teaTypeRepository) {
        this.teaTypeRepository = teaTypeRepository;
    }
    //


    // METHODS
    //
    public List<Countries> findCountries(){
        return countriesRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Manufacturer> findManufacturers(){
        return manufacturerRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Roasting> findRoastings(){
        return roastingRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Packaging> findPackagings(){
        return packagingRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<TeaColor> findTeaColors(){
        return teaColorRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<CoffeeType> findCoffeeTypes(){
        return coffeeTypeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<TeaType> findTeaTypeS(){
        return teaTypeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

CatalogController:

```java
@Api(value = "Catalog", tags = {"catalog"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class CatalogController<T> {

    private CatalogService catalogService;

    @Autowired
    public CatalogService getCatalogService() {
        return catalogService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/countries")
    public List<Countries> findCountries(){
        return catalogService.findCountries();
    }

    @GetMapping("/manufacturers")
    public List<Manufacturer> findManufacturers(){
        return catalogService.findManufacturers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/roastings")
    public List<Roasting> findRoastings(){
        return catalogService.findRoastings();
    }

    @GetMapping("/packagings")
    public List<Packaging> findPackagings(){
        return catalogService.findPackagings();
    }

    @GetMapping("/teacolors")
    public List<TeaColor> findTeaColors(){
        return catalogService.findTeaColors();
    }

    @GetMapping("/coffeetypes")
    public List<CoffeeType> findCoffeeTypes(){
        return catalogService.findCoffeeTypes();
    }

    @GetMapping("/teatypes")
    public List<TeaType> findTeaTypeS(){
        return catalogService.findTeaTypeS();
    }
}
```

For example one interface:

```java
public interface CountriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Countries, Long> {
}
```

[image]

[image]

Maybe it will be possible to generalize all this somehow?

Comment: You can't query for a MappedSuperclass so there's not much you can do here. You could however look at using  the Spring Data Rest extension to have controllers auto generated at run-time for these repositories. So you could then scrap the controllwer and service classes and  just configure REST extension for CRUD (or subset of CRUD operations).

Comment: Could you provide a link to this topic or suggest how to google it?

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made methods to make simple jpa things, you can see more at https://github.com/fajaralmu/base_web_app

example :

```
public List<Page> getAllPages() {
        List<Page> allPages = entityRepository.findAll(Page.class);
        
        return   allPages;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use hibernate and criteria api directly to handle your use case.

It's straight as:

`session.createCriteria(entityClass).list()`